# How can I remove an empty main menu category in Ubuntu Budgie 19.04?

Tags: menu, budgie

I've added with the Menu Editor an app to the menu under Applications, but then the system created an empty bottom category entry of "Other" (as seen in the picture - https://pasteboard.co/IsFHcd9.png). I don't know how to remove it, and using [menulibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre) as suggested at https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MenuLibre-2.1.5-Released and http://forum.manjaro.org/t/budgie-menu-configure-edit-how-to/44669 or editing .desktop files (op cit.) only made another empty menu entry.

Comment: Is it possible to delete non-empty menu categories? If so, add something to the empty category and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone in finding Menulibre an unsatisfactory (albeit official) solution [Issue 789](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/789) [Issue 939](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/939). You may wish to add your voice to those assembled multitudes to encourage a satisfactory solution. Until then, have you tried [Appeditor](https://github.com/donadigo/appeditor) ([more](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/app-menu-editor-for-ubuntu-appeditor))? That requires:

```
sudo apt install flatpak  
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub  https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
sudo flatpak install flathub com.github.donadigo.appeditor
```

Comment: When adding the flathub, if I do a distro upgrade in the future will there be problems?

Comment: There's so much momentum behind flatpacks that I believe not.

Answer (score 0):

As for K7AAY, I found menulibre to be the cause on my system. I would just comment on his answer if I had enough reputation.

Alacarte showed the empty categories to contain custom-generated menu items. They were stored as "menulibre-..." .desktop files in .local/share/applications .

I deleted them and created new ones with alacarte, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had an additional menu entry created for me as well, in the system menus, so that there was a duplicate *menu* with one single *entry* repeated in that menu, although I can't be sure if it was when I pressed "save" in `menulibre` or if an application installed it.

I tracked it down to an `applications-merged` entry in `~/.config/menus`:

```
$ cd ~/.config
$ ll -R menus/
menus/:
total 4.0K
drwx------ 2 neil neil 4.0K Jul 24 13:12 applications-merged
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neil neil   19 Jul 24 13:12 gnome-applications-merged -> applications-merged

menus/applications-merged:
total 4.0K
-rw------- 1 neil neil 421 Jul 24 13:12 user-xfce-network.menu
```

I didn't have any other files in there so I was able to `rm -rf ~/.config/menus` and the next time I clicked the menu button the extra entry was gone.

Removing the particular `*.menu` entry should be sufficient.

I decided to continue using manual edits and because of some internal inconsistencies displayed within menulibre itself:

```
sudo apt purge menulibre
```

You can refer to the FreeDesktop menu and file locations spec for guidance in managing your applications and menus manually:

- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/
- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s02.html

To understand the menus better the `xdg-desktop-menu` man page is a compact and fast introduction to the main points you need to know to find and manage your menus. You may find other useful commands by searching on "menu" or "xdg":

```
$ man -k xdg
user-dirs.conf (5)   - configuration for xdg-user-dirs-update
user-dirs.defaults (5) - default settings for XDG user dirs
user-dirs.dirs (5)   - settings for XDG user dirs
xdg-dbus-proxy (1)   - D-Bus proxy
xdg-desktop-icon (1) - command line tool for (un)installing icons to the desktop
xdg-desktop-menu (1) - command line tool for (un)installing desktop menu items
xdg-email (1)        - command line tool for sending mail using the user's preferred e-mail composer
xdg-icon-resource (1) - command line tool for (un)installing icon resources
xdg-mime (1)         - command line tool for querying information about file type handling and adding descriptions for new file types
xdg-open (1)         - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
xdg-screensaver (1)  - command line tool for controlling the screensaver
xdg-settings (1)     - get various settings from the desktop environment
xdg-user-dir (1)     - Find an XDG user dir
xdg-user-dirs-update (1) - Update XDG user dir configuration

$ man -k menu
grub-menulst2cfg (1) - transform legacy menu.lst into grub.cfg
menulibre (1)        - advanced fd.o compliant menu editor
menulibre-menu-validate (1) - display GMenu debug output
xdg-desktop-menu (1) - command line tool for (un)installing desktop menu items
xfce4-popup-menu (1) - shows the Xfce Menu
xfce4-popup-whiskermenu (1) - shows Whisker Menu
```

I also found `desktop-file-validate` is separately available from menulibre in Xubuntu. This validator found no problems with a desktop file that menulibre was inconsistently complaining about:

```
$ sudo desktop-file-validate /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```